# system.webServer/fastCgi/application not working in web.config

Tags: iis, webmatrix, msdeploy, web-platform-installer

How do I register an IIS FastCGI application in a MSDeploy's `web.config` file [as documented](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi/application#005)?

I'm trying to build a simple test MS Web Deploy package installable by
the Web Platform Installer via a [custom feed](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/10/24/web-pi-extensibility-custom-feeds-installing-custom-applications.aspx).  I'm trying to
register a FastCGI application in the packages `web.config` as the
[docs indicate is possible](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi/application#005).  You can see the [web.config file below
or in github](https://github.com/rpatterson/iiswsgi/blob/9b64c08fffdd8a3110e976160037576f907bdc96/sample.msdeploy/IISWSGISampleApp/web.config):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <fastCgi>
      <application fullPath="C:\Python27\python.exe" arguments="-u C:\Python27\Scripts\iiswsgi-script.py" monitorChangesTo="C:\Python27\Scripts\iiswsgi-script.py" maxInstances="1" />
    </fastCgi>
...
```

This doesn't work when installed via the Web Platform Installer and then tested through Web Matrix/IIS Express.  However, as soon as I run the `appcmd.exe` command as below and in the [`install.cmd` batch file](https://github.com/rpatterson/iiswsgi/blob/9b64c08fffdd8a3110e976160037576f907bdc96/install.cmd):

```
set IIS_BIN=%ProgramFiles%\IIS Express
"%IIS_BIN%\appcmd.exe" set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='%SystemDrive%\Python27\python.exe',arguments='-u %SystemDrive%\Python27\Scripts\iiswsgi-script.py',maxInstances='1',monitorChangesTo='%SystemDrive%\Python27\Scripts\iiswsgi-script.py']" /commit:apphost
```

...the FastCGI app works just fine.  IOW, it seems like the `<fastCGI><application>` elements in `web.config` don't take effect, but they do in IIS's `applicationhost.config` even though the docs indicate this is possible in `web.confg`.

Is there a way to get this to work in the specific app (through `web.config` or otherwise) without changing the global IIS config?

I'm doing all this under Windows 7 Professional, Web Platform
Installer 4.0, and Web Matrix 2.0 RC whose about dialog says:

```
Version 2.0 RC
WebMatrix: 7.1.1587.0
IIS Express: 8.0.8298.0
.NET Framework: 4.0.30319.17379 built by: FXBETAREL
Web Deploy: 7.1.1516.0
SQL Server Compact: 4.0.8854.1
Web Platform Installer: 7.1.1586.1
ASP.NET Web Pages: 2.0.20505.0
ASP.NET Web Pages: 1.0.20105.407
```

The code behind all this is in [IISWSGI on GitHub](https://github.com/rpatterson/iiswsgi), [use this commit](https://github.com/rpatterson/iiswsgi/commit/9b64c08fffdd8a3110e976160037576f907bdc96) to test.  To reproduce the
environment I'm using, see the [IISWSGI documentation](https://github.com/rpatterson/iiswsgi#sample-package).

Comment: Have you looked at deploying it via the [`fcgiExtConfig`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619746%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) MSDeploy provider?

Comment: @RichardSzalay Using that fails with `EXCEPTION: Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: Source (fcgiExtConfig=ini) and destination (fcgiExtConfig=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\fcgiext.ini) are not compatible for the given operation. ---> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Found invalid data while decoding.`  After reading the docs I'm not sure how it would work for WebPI/IIS Express anyways.